# PowerShell console timer

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am attempting to create a simple console timer display.

```
...

$rpt = $null
write-status "Opening report", $rpt

# long-running
$rpt = rpt-open -path "C:\Documents and Settings\foobar\Desktop\Calendar.rpt"

...

function write-status ($msg, $obj) {

    write-host "$msg" -nonewline

    do {
        sleep -seconds 1
        write-host "." -nonewline
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() 
    } while ($obj -eq $null)

    write-host

}
```

The example generates 'Opening report ....', but the loop never exits.

I should probably use a call-back or delegate, but I'm not sure of the pattern in this situation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`Write-Progress`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849902.aspx) to inform the user of the run status of your process and update it as events warrant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some "parallel" computing with powershell use jobs.

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Open-File $file} -ArgumentList $file
while($job.status -eq 'Running'){
    Write-Host '.' -NoNewLine
}
```

Here is what I think about [Write-Host](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

The script runs in sequence. When you input a `$null` object, the while condition will always be true. The function will continue forever until something breaks it (which never happends in your script.

First then will it be done with the function and continue with your next lines:

```
# long-running
$rpt = rpt-open -path "C:\Documents and Settings\foobar\Desktop\Calendar.rpt"
```

Summary: Your while loop works like `while($true)` atm = bad design